# Binding an ImageView size to an AnchorPane always gives a size of 0

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have an `ImageView` inside an `AnchorPane`, built using FXML.

```
<fx:root prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LifeMandelbrot">
  <children>
    <ImageView fx:id="view" fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="800.0" onMouseClicked="#moveCenter" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <Button fx:id="zoomOut" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#zoomOut" text="Zoom-" />
        <Button fx:id="zoomIn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#zoomIn" text="Zoom+" />
        <Button fx:id="defaultView" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#defaultView" text="Vue par défaut" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

As you can see, the `ImageView` fits the `AnchorPane` using anchors.

When I click one of the button, the `ImageView` is repainted.

**Problem:**
`view.getFitWidth()` always shows `0`, same for the height.

---

**EDIT**

The controller code looks like that:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class LifeMandelbrot extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {
    private static final double DEFAULT_ZOOM = 200.0;
    private static final Complex DEFAULT_CENTER = new Complex(0, 0);
    private static final double ZOOM_RATIO = 1.2;
    @FXML
    private Button zoomOut;

    @FXML
    private Button zoomIn;

    @FXML
    private Button defaultView;

    @FXML
    private Button julia;

    @FXML
    ImageView view;

    private double zoom;
    private Complex center;
    private List<Color> colors;
    private int colorStep;

    public LifeMandelbrot() {
    zoom = DEFAULT_ZOOM;
    center = DEFAULT_CENTER;
    colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
    colors.add(Color.RED);
    colors.add(Color.GREEN);
    colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    colorStep = 20;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    repaint();
    view.fitWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
    view.fitHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
    }

    @FXML
    void defaultView(ActionEvent event) {
    zoom = DEFAULT_ZOOM;
    center = DEFAULT_CENTER;
    repaint();
    }

    @FXML
    void julia(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    void zoomIn(ActionEvent event) {
    zoom *= ZOOM_RATIO;
    repaint();
    }

    @FXML
    void zoomOut(ActionEvent event) {
    zoom /= ZOOM_RATIO;
    repaint();
    }

    @FXML
    void moveCenter(MouseEvent event) {
    center = fractalFromView(event.getX(), event.getY());
    repaint();
    }

    private void repaint() {
    WritableImage image = new WritableImage((int) view.getFitWidth(), (int) view.getFitHeight());
    PixelWriter pw = image.getPixelWriter();
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        Complex c = fractalFromView(x, y);
        int iterations = Fractal.mandelbrot(c);
        if (iterations == -1) {
            pw.setColor(x, y, new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));
        } else {
            int colorIndex = iterations / colorStep;
            int colorAdd = iterations % colorStep;
            Color color1 = colors.get(colorIndex % colors.size());
            Color color2 = colors.get((colorIndex + 1) % colors.size());
            Color color = color1.interpolate(color2, (double) colorAdd / colorStep);
            pw.setColor(x, y, color);
        }
        }
    }
    view.setImage(image);
    }

    private Complex fractalFromView(double x, double y) {
    return new Complex((x - view.getFitWidth() / 2) / zoom + center.getReal(),
        (y - view.getFitHeight() / 2) / zoom + center.getImaginary());
    }
}
```

Loaded from there:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../lifeMandelbrot.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(new LifeMandelbrot());
        AnchorPane root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("LIFE Is a Fractal Explorer");
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to believe it returns 0 when you explicitly set it to 800. Can you show the controller code?

Comment: It's the same, my bad. I'll change that.

Comment: What is `widthProperty()` in the controller? And, I guess, where and when are you trying to get the value of `fitWdith`?

Comment: The controller inherits AnchorPane.

Comment: Something seems really wrong with the way you have this set up. Which `AnchorPane` are you setting as the root? Do you have a controller factory set on the `FXMLLoader`? I guess it would help to show the code where you load the FXML (and what the context of that code is).

Comment: Done! Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of `LifeMandelbrot`: one you create by calling the constructor and explicitly set as the dynamic root of the FXML; the other is created for you by the `FXMLLoader` and is used as the controller. The one you create you use in the scene graph (`scene = new Scene(root)`). The one that is created as the controller is never placed in the scene graph. Consequently it never undergoes layout and always has width and height of zero.

Of course, the handler methods and `initialize()` methods are called on the "controller instance", not the "root instance", so you bind `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` to zero.

You need

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../lifeMandelbrot.fxml"));
LifeMandelbrot root = new LifeMandelbrot();
loader.setRoot(root);
loader.setController(root);
loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

and then you need to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the root element of the FXML. This way the controller and root node are the same instance.

Since your FXML already explicitly ties itself to an `AnchorPane` by using the anchor pane settings on the child nodes, it might be clearer just to use the standard pattern for this. I.e.

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" fx:controller="application.LifeMandelbrot" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <ImageView fx:id="view" onMouseClicked="#moveCenter" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <Button fx:id="zoomOut" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#zoomOut" text="Zoom-" />
        <Button fx:id="zoomIn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#zoomIn" text="Zoom+" />
        <Button fx:id="defaultView" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#defaultView" text="Vue par défaut" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In the controller:

```
public class LifeMandelbrot implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root ;

    // existing code...

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        repaint();
        view.fitWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
        view.fitHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());
    }    

    // existing code...
}
```

and then just

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../lifeMandelbrot.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still new at JavaFX and especially FXML. I'll understand everything eventually.

Comment: The second version returns so many errors I'll stick with the first one.

Comment: I had left `type="..."` in the root element of the FXML, which obviously makes no sense when you don't have a dynamic root, so that was probably all that was wrong. (Unless you have other code in the controller assuming it is a subclass of `AnchorPane`.) You might be interested in https://github.com/james-d/ZoomingMandelbrot ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I won't miss to check your version of the software. You can see the previous buggy version of mine (I was still unexperienced) at https://github.com/SteeveDroz/life